# How can i retrive session from asp.net using Jquery

Tags: asp.net

How can I retrieve session variable stored in a.aspx using Jquery? I have username stored in the session, I need to retrieve the session to display the username in the menu bar.
A person login through A.aspx and his details has to be displayed(from database) in B.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would be to create a Web Method or similar within your current page so that you could access the updated value of the Session via an AJAX call :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSessionValue(string key)
{
     return Session[key];
}
```

Then you could make a `POST` call via AJAX to request the specific key that you needed (or you could ignore any parameters and simply hard-code the key that you wanted to pull within the method itself) :

```
public static string GetSessionDisplayName()
{
     // Use the name of your Session key here to retrieve your info
     return Session["DisplayName"];
}
```

And then you could use the following jQuery code to pull it with a parameter :

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "YourPage.aspx/GetSessionValue",
     data: '{ key: "your-session-key" }',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
           // data will hold your Session value, use it here
           alert(data);
     }
});
```

Or without one :

```
$.post('YourPage.aspx/GetSessionDisplayName',function(data){
    // data will hold your Session value, use it here
    alert(data);
});
```